# Increment and Decrement Firebase Ionic 5

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic5

I would like of increment +1 and decrement -1 in database firebase with the simple method

```
increment() {
  const i = +1;
  this.service.update(i)
}


decrement() {
  const i = -1;
  this.service.update(i)
}
```

and service I have the simple code

```
update(panel: Panel) {
return this.db.object(`${this.path}/${panel.codeLed}`)
    .update(panel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code and to me, worked fine

```
incrementUp(panel: Panel) {
   return this.db.object(`${this.path}/${panel.codeLed}/up`)
    .query.ref.transaction(ups => {
      if (ups === null) {
        return ups = 1;
      } else {
        return ups + 1;
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `increment` operator, which is used like this from the regular JavaScript SDK

```
firebase.database().ref('/path/to/value').update({ firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1) })
```

Comment: how can import "firebase" waths library ?

Comment: because I'm using AngularFireDatabase

Comment: The above will also work when you'r already using AngularFire. You'll just need to import the Firebase JavaScript SDK in addition to AngularFire. How to do that depends on your build system, but should be in the options on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup